# Dividing 2 numbers returns 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I'm trying to divide 2 counts in order to return a percentage.

The following query is returning `0`:

```
select (
    (select COUNT(*) from saxref..AuthCycle
         where endOfUse is null and addDate >= '1/1/2014') / 
    (select COUNT(*) from saxref..AuthCycle 
         where addDate >= '1/1/2014')
    ) as Percentage
```

Should I be applying a cast?

Comment: Add `1.0 *` (or `100.0 *`) to that, if it's sql-server.

Comment: Which SQL you are using.. SQL Server ???, mySQL etc...

Comment: `COUNT(*) * 100` (or `100*(SELECT)`) for the first first value.

Comment: Syntactically everything looks correct. Can't speak for the data itself obviously. Consider switching to use of CASE statements like in @PatrickHofman's answer below. The execution path will be shorter since only a single read of the table is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it differently, using two `sum`s:

```
select sum
       ( case
         when endOfUse is null and addDate >= '1/1/2014'
         then 1
         else 0
         end
       )
       * 100.0 -- if you want the usual 0..100 range for percentages
       /
       sum
       ( case
         when addDate >= '1/1/2014'
         then 1
         else 0
         end
       )
       percentage
from   saxref..AuthCycle
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is caused because you are dividing 2 `int` values, which by default will output an `int` as it takes the data types used in the calculation to determine the data type of the output, so effectively if you do this:

```
select 50/100 as result
```

You get `0.5` output as `0` as it rounds it to an `int` (no decimal places).

If you however specify decimals:

```
select 50.0/100.0 as result
```

You would get `0.5` as a decimal, which you could multiply by 100 to get 50%.

So updating your syntax to multiply by `1.0` and making the counts into decimals would give you the correct result:

```
select (
(select COUNT(*) from saxref..AuthCycle where endOfUse is null and addDate >= '1/1/2014')*1.0 / 
(select COUNT(*) from saxref..AuthCycle where addDate >= '1/1/2014')*1.0
) as Percentage
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done more succinctly by moving the common condition to the where clause:

```
select sum(case when endOfUse is null then 1 end) * 100.0 / count(*) percentage
from saxref..AuthCycle
where addDate >= '1/1/2014'
```

Note how you don't need the case of `0` for false either, since nulls are ignored with `sum()`